# Result is not showing when I search a category with "&" keyword

Tags: php, wordpress

When I search a category name with "&" then the search result is not showing in wordpress admin section.
For example : when I search with key word "& test" then showing "No categories found." but when I search with only keyword "test" then it returns actual result.
But in my category section there is a category name "test & test".

Can you inform me why this type of error occur and how to fix it.

Comment: maybe the search is more of an auto complete rather than a "LIKE" search. So when you type a search it will look for keyword% rather than %keyword%

Comment: this issue occur in wordpress back end category section. I did't add any coding in theme or plugin.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/searching-with-ampersands

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's hard to tell what's going on, but I'm going to take a stab in the dark anyway because encoding is not easily understood by most people.

If you're adding a search term to a url, such as:

```
?search=some text to search for
```

You need to URL encode the value being searched for. Most characters will work fine without proper url encoding (because the system is designed to work even when the input is bad), but `&` characters **will not**.

Properly encoding the value above would be:

```
?search=some%20text%20to%20search%20for
```

or possibly (both `+` and `%20` may be used to represent space characters):

```
?search=some+text+to+search+for
```

It's likely that you've got code that simply concatenate's a value into a query string without escaping special characters. Within a query string, the `&` character is used to separate different key-value pairs. Simply URL encode the value so that it reads as:

```
?search=test%20%26%20test
```

And the search should be able to properly read the value passed.